# Windows API - Getting an Image From Some Windows Does Not Work

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

This is a question related to getting an image from a window external to myself. I'm using Java JNA for a certain level of window interaction (i.e. get an image from a window that is not mine and send input to it).

To get the image, I'm using the following Java JNA function: `GDI32Util.getScreenshot(handle);`.

In general this function was working ok on other windows that I tried. However, I noticed now on 2 programs the image would be stale. Basically this function would return the same image over and over and never actually update. My (poor) understanding is that the DC is cached and you get that version, so it almost seems like it's cached one time and never updated unless I restart the window itself, and then again it is only cached once and returned over and over.

Both windows that I'm having problems with are Unity windows (`UnityWndClass`) again these are windows that I don't own, I just want them to give me an image.

Here is a link to the getScreenshot function I am using from JNA: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/GDI32Util.java

I've tried modifying the code below in various ways but had no luck getting it to give me an accurate, and up to date image. I'm no expert on Win API (or anything, to be fair). Any suggestions?

```
public class GDI32Util {

    private static final DirectColorModel SCREENSHOT_COLOR_MODEL = new DirectColorModel(24, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF00, 0xFF);
    private static final int[] SCREENSHOT_BAND_MASKS = {
        SCREENSHOT_COLOR_MODEL.getRedMask(),
        SCREENSHOT_COLOR_MODEL.getGreenMask(),
        SCREENSHOT_COLOR_MODEL.getBlueMask()
    };

    /**
     * Takes a screenshot of the given window
     *
     * @param target The window to target
     *
     * @return the window captured as a screenshot, or null if the BufferedImage
     *         doesn't construct properly
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the rectangle from GetWindowRect has a
     *                               width and/or height of 0. <br>
     * if the device context acquired from the original HWND doesn't release
     * properly
     */
    public static BufferedImage getScreenshot(HWND target) {
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        if (!User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(target, rect)) {
            throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
        }
        Rectangle jRectangle = rect.toRectangle();
        int windowWidth = jRectangle.width;
        int windowHeight = jRectangle.height;

        if (windowWidth == 0 || windowHeight == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Window width and/or height were 0 even though GetWindowRect did not appear to fail.");
        }

        HDC hdcTarget = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(target);
        if (hdcTarget == null) {
            throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
        }

        Win32Exception we = null;

        // device context used for drawing
        HDC hdcTargetMem = null;

        // handle to the bitmap to be drawn to
        HBITMAP hBitmap = null;

        // original display surface associated with the device context
        HANDLE hOriginal = null;

        // final java image structure we're returning.
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            hdcTargetMem = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcTarget);
            if (hdcTargetMem == null) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
            }

            hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcTarget, windowWidth, windowHeight);
            if (hBitmap == null) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
            }

            hOriginal = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcTargetMem, hBitmap);
            if (hOriginal == null) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
            }

            // draw to the bitmap
            if (!GDI32.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcTargetMem, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, hdcTarget, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY)) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
            }

            BITMAPINFO bmi = new BITMAPINFO();
            bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = windowWidth;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -windowHeight;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;

            Memory buffer = new Memory(windowWidth * windowHeight * 4);
            int resultOfDrawing = GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcTarget, hBitmap, 0, windowHeight, buffer, bmi,
                    WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);
            if (resultOfDrawing == 0 || resultOfDrawing == WinError.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
                throw new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
            }

            int bufferSize = windowWidth * windowHeight;
            DataBuffer dataBuffer = new DataBufferInt(buffer.getIntArray(0, bufferSize), bufferSize);
            WritableRaster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(dataBuffer, windowWidth, windowHeight, windowWidth,
                    SCREENSHOT_BAND_MASKS, null);
            image = new BufferedImage(SCREENSHOT_COLOR_MODEL, raster, false, null);

        } catch (Win32Exception e) {
            we = e;
        } finally {
            if (hOriginal != null) {
                // per MSDN, set the display surface back when done drawing
                HANDLE result = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcTargetMem, hOriginal);
                // failure modes are null or equal to HGDI_ERROR
                if (result == null || WinGDI.HGDI_ERROR.equals(result)) {
                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
                    if (we != null) {
                        ex.addSuppressedReflected(we);
                    }
                    we = ex;
                }
            }

            if (hBitmap != null) {
                if (!GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap)) {
                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
                    if (we != null) {
                        ex.addSuppressedReflected(we);
                    }
                    we = ex;
                }
            }

            if (hdcTargetMem != null) {
                // get rid of the device context when done
                if (!GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteDC(hdcTargetMem)) {
                    Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(Native.getLastError());
                    if (we != null) {
                        ex.addSuppressedReflected(we);
                    }
                    we = ex;
                }
            }

            if (hdcTarget != null) {
                if (0 == User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(target, hdcTarget)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Device context did not release properly.");
                }
            }
        }

        if (we != null) {
            throw we;
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

I tried using the JNA function `GDI32Util.getScreenshot(handle)` and expected the result to be a `BufferedImage` which is constantly updated every time I query, however the image is stale and seems to be constantly returning a cached image instead.

Comment: Some windows are configured so they can't be captured using SetWindowDisplayAffinity(...WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE...) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity some other Windows can't be capture because their content is protected (copyright, etc.). In other words, you cannot capture *any* window.

Comment: Are there any suggestions you have to try and get this working? The SetWindowDisplayAffinity says "Everywhere else, the window does not appear at all. " which makes me think the display context would be empty, or something? I'm actually getting a valid image, but the image does not actively update after the initial query.

Comment: If you get an image, it means you're not in the "protected" scenario. Difficult to say more, I don't know how GDI32Util.getScreenshot is coded.

Comment: @SimonMourier  I have pasted the snippet from the GDI32Util.getScreenshot function in my OP above. Any recommendations I can try to modify to see if I get different results? I feel there is something that needs to be done to force the DC to redraw before copying it but I was not able to get it working myself.

Comment: Edit: To me (and my limited knowledge of WinAPI) it seems like what is happening is something like this:  

The window is open for the first time
I call get screenshot function
DC is copied out successfully, and then replaced by SelectObject(hdcTargetMem, hOriginal)
Somehow this does not restore the DC correctly
Next time I get the DC, I get this incorrectly restored DC again which contains the same image content

Only by restarting the window do I get a new image again (for a single time) and then the process repeats.

Comment: Edit-edit: The window has the following class styles:
CS_OWNDC 
CS_VREDRAW
CS_HREDRAW
CS_DBLCLKS

I wonder if the CS_OWNDC is the problem with the private DC.